# Google_client refreshToken and documentation

Tags: google-client

I have 2 problems.

1-I can't found the php Google_client (and other components) documentation (methods,vars,etc..)
2-After creation token i can find the refrehTOken on json object generate in authentication

I have tried to remove from the console permission to regenerate the token as if for the first time, but in the json "refreshToken" does not exist. But in web application is it possibile use refreshtoken???how to?

please insert example is possibile.

Comment: The refresh token is present, if you create Google client in mode offline

$client->setClientId(CLIENTID);
$client->setClientSecret(CLIENTSECRET);
**$client->setAccessType('offline');**
After it's possibile find the refresh token on json data

Comment: before you must revoke the past token with **$client->revokeToken();**